# Order a Group BY

Tags: mysql, sql

There are alot questions on this topic, still can't figure out a way to make this work.

The query I'm doing is:

```
SELECT `b`.`ads_id`     AS `ads_id`,
  `b`.`bod_bedrag`      AS `bod_bedrag`,
  `a`. `ads_naam`       AS `ads_naam`,
  `a`.`ads_url`         AS `ads_url`,
  `a`.`ads_prijs`       AS `ads_price`,
  `i`.`url`             AS `img_url`,
  `c`.`url`             AS `cat_url`
FROM `ads_market_bids`  AS `b`
INNER JOIN `ads_market` AS `a`
ON `b`.`ads_id` = `a`.`id`
INNER JOIN `ads_images` AS `i`
ON `b`.`ads_id` = `i`.`ads_id`
INNER JOIN `ads_categories` AS `c`
ON `a`.`cat_id`       = `c`.`id`
WHERE `i`.`img_order` = '0'
AND `b`.`u_id`        = '285'
GROUP BY `b`.`ads_id`
HAVING MAX(b.bod_bedrag)
ORDER BY `b`.`bod_bedrag` ASC
```

But, the problem I keep seeing is that I need b.bod_bedrag to be sorted before the GROUP BY is taking place or so. Don't know how to explain it exactly.

The bod_bedrag i'm getting now are the lowest of the bids in the table. I need the highest.

Tried like everything, even tought of not grouping by but using DISTINCT. This didn't work either. Tried order by max, everything I know or could find on the internet.

Image 1 is the situation without the group by. Order By works great (ofc).
[image: No Group By]
 Image 2 is with the group by. As you can see, the lowest bid is taken as bod_bedrag. I need the highest.
[image: With Group By]

Comment: `Order by` takes place after `group by`.  You should also learn to avoid the MySQL `group by` extension that you are using:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html.

Comment: `The bod_bedrag i'm getting now are the lowest of the bids in the table. I need the highest.` put simply, you just shouldn't rely on a single field in the `group by` clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your output you want:

```
  SELECT amb.ads_id,
         MAX(amb.bod_bedrag) max_bod_bedrag,
         am.ads_naam,
         am.ads_url,
         am.ads_prijs ads_price,
         ai.url img_url,
         ac.url cat_url
    FROM ads_market_bids amb 
    JOIN ads_images ai 
      ON ai.ads_id = amb.ads_id
     AND ai.img_order = 0
    JOIN ads_market am 
      ON am.id = amb.ads_id 
    JOIN ads_categories ac
      ON ac.id = am.cat_id 
   WHERE amb.u_id = 285 
GROUP BY amb.ads_id, 
         am.ads_naam,
         am.ads_url,
         am.ads_prijs,
         ai.url,
         ac.url
ORDER BY max_bod_bedrag ASC
```

I have also removed all the unecessary backtickery and aliasing of columns to the same name.
Your `HAVING` was doing nothing as all the groups 'have' a `MAX(amb.bod_rag)`.

Comment: The backticks are created by Eloquent, but indeed, they suck. This answer works, I'll now put it in Eloquent style, thank you!

Comment: @Chilion Eloquent.. the irony.

Comment: I don't get the irony of it? Please enlighten me?

Comment: @Chilion Look up the dictionary definition of the word eloquent!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to simulate row_number() (which MySQL does not have), but it allows for selection - by record - rather than by aggregates which may come from disparate source records. It works by adding to variables to each row (it does **not** increase the number of rows) Then, using an ordered subquery those variables are set to 1 for the highest `b`.`bod_bedrag` for each `b`.`ads_id, all other rows per`b`.`ads_id` get a higher RN value. At the end we filter where RN = 1 (which equates the the record containing the highest bid value)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT
           @row_num :=IF(@prev_value=`b`.`ads_id`, @row_num + 1, 1) AS RN
          ,`b`.`ads_id` AS `ads_id`
          ,`b`.`bod_bedrag` AS `bod_bedrag`
          ,`a`.`ads_naam` AS `ads_naam`
          ,`a`.`ads_url` AS `ads_url`
          ,`a`.`ads_prijs` AS `ads_price`
          ,`i`.`url` AS `img_url`
          ,`c`.`url` AS `cat_url`
          , @prev_value := `b`.`bod_bedrag`
       FROM `ads_market_bids` AS `b`
       INNER JOIN `ads_market` AS `a`     ON `b`.`ads_id` = `a`.`id`
       INNER JOIN `ads_images` AS `i`     ON `b`.`ads_id` = `i`.`ads_id`
       INNER JOIN `ads_categories` AS `c` ON `a`.`cat_id` = `c`.`id`
       CROSS JOIN
          ( SELECT @row_num :=1
             , @prev_value :=''
          ) vars
       WHERE `i`.`img_order` = '0'
       AND `b`.`u_id` = '285'
       ORDER BY `b`.`ads_id`, b`.`bod_bedrag` DESC
       )
WHERE RN = 1;
```

---

You can even turn off that silly GROUP BY extension, details in the man page:
[MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct `b`.`ads_id` as `ads_id`, max(`b`.`bod_bedrag`) as `bod_bedrag`, 
`a`.`ads_naam` as `ads_naam`, `a`.`ads_url` as `ads_url`, `a`.`ads_prijs` as `ads_price`,
`i`.`url` as `img_url`, `c`.`url` as `cat_url` 
 from `ads_market_bids` as `b` 
   inner join `ads_market` as `a` on `b`.`ads_id` = `a`.`id` 
   inner join `ads_images` as `i` on `b`.`ads_id` = `i`.`ads_id` 
   inner join `ads_categories` as `c` on `a`.`cat_id` = `c`.`id` 
 where `i`.`img_order` = '0' and `b`.`u_id` = '285' 
 group by b.ads_id, a.ads_naam, a.ads_url, a.ads_prijs, i.url, c.url
```

Comment: Guess this does the same as the answer above you. Despite that it works, I tried the other one first. Thx!